# How to where clause the current id of Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to put the current id of my Model in my **where** clause where I need to get the current comment for that document id. Please see my Controller below.

**Controller**

```
public function readSentDocuments($id)
{
    $documentLists = Document::find($id);

    $commentLists = DB::table('comments')->select('comments.comment', 'users.username')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.sender_id')
    ->where('document_id', '=', $documentLists->id);

    return view ('document.readSent')->with('documentLists', $documentLists)->with('commentLists', $commentLists);

}
```

As you can see here I **where** clause the `document_id` to the instance of my Model. Which where I'm accessing the current document. I also tried to **where** clause the current id of my Model which is 176.  `where('document_id', '=', 176);` But still cannot retrieve those values.

**Database Columns**

[image]

**View**

```
<div class = "col-md-6">

    <form class = "form-vertical">

        <div class = "form-group">

            <label for = "thread" class = "control-label">Thread</label>

            <br>

            @foreach ($commentLists as $list)
                <p>{{ $list->comment }}</p>
                <p>{{ $list->username }}</p>
            @endforeach

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/sent/documents/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readSentDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.readSent',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

Comment: Why don't you do this using `Eloquent ORM`? .. Such as `$document->commentLists()`. As I can see it is a `hasMany` relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `get()` the result...

```
$commentLists = DB::table('comments')->select('comments.comment', 'users.username')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.sender_id')
->where('document_id', '=', $documentLists->id)->get();
```

Comment: It's not showing to me the values in `<p></p>` tag. Any help why it doesn't show?

Comment: @Francisunoxx : Maybe your statement doesn't return any result. Try `dd($commentLists)` just before returning the view in your controller